# Audacity Says "Error Locking Temporary Folder" and Won't Open

Tags: applications

I was using Audacity and it kept saying that it couldn't save to the autosave folder. I went to turn it off and it said it couldn't save its user configuration file. Now, when I try to turn it off, it says "Error Locking Temporary Folder." What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not enough space on my computer, the hard drive was full. I had to delete some stuff in order to open Audacity again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem as the result of a crash whilst working in Audacity.  It wouldn't go away for several days, until I worked out how to locate and delete the temporary lock file. 
On a Mac, it is called "audacity-lock-", located in Audacity's  "SessionData" folder, within your "Application Support/audacity" folder, generally found in your Library folder (which Mac has taken to hiding, these days, by default).

If you're struggling to find this folder on your Mac, here is the rather laborious solution post in Audacity's forums:

https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=88589#p290898